# Consider the function$ f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ given by$ f(n) = n^2.$ Write down the set $f ^{−1} (\{9, 10\}).$

Tags: functions

How can I solve this?
I think they for $f$ inverse $9$. Answer is $3$. And for $f$ inverse $10$ I am confused. Is this possible to find the solution for $f$ inverse $10$?

Comment: What would map to $10$ under $f$? This would be an integer $n$ such that $n^2=10$. Is there such an integer?

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: For a set $S$, the notation $f^{-1}(S)$ doesn't mean inverse of each individual element. In fact $f$ doesn't even need to be invertible (as your function for example is not). What $f^{-1}(\{9,10\})$ means is all integers that are mapped to either $9$ or $10$. Since $10$ is not square of any integer, it doesn't contribute to $f^{-1}(\{9,10\})$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition $f^{-1} (\{9,10\})$ is the set of all integers $n$ such that $n^{2}=9$ or $n^{2}=10$. The answer therefore is $\{-3,3\}$.

Comment: But what about 10?  Like we can't find anything for that right because the sqareroot is not integer right?

Comment: Yes, square root of $10$  is not an integer so you are left with just $3$ and $-3$. @KaranSingh